# shared security between websphere and tomcat

Tags: java, security, tomcat, websphere

Currently have WebSphere with some EJBs and defined custom user registry based on DB.

Now I am planning new application on Tomcat, which :

- has same users as existing WebSphere
- share access to the same DB
- has to call EJB from WebSphere as logged user (results of call depend of calling user )

  1. Is it possible to call WebSphere EJB from Tomcat with security ?
     Probably yes, but if :

Users in DB have hashed passwords, Tomcat app during user login can hash entered password and determine if valid, but now if I call WebSphere EJB, I assume I should provide password (to InitialContext?), but no one knows it?

Does Anyone have idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirt and quick: Store unhashed password in Tomcat session and use it. Remember not to serialize it!

Alternative: Explore what kerberos does. I am not very familiar with it, but its objective seems exactly the same that you are looking for (kerberos centralices authentication and returns ticket that give access to the resources). Sorry I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, storing password in session looks ugly, but it is fastest way to implement. I ll look later at other solutions with tickets..